# Copy paste data (with formatting,formulas, charts, images) into multiple excel worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to copy paste data to multiple worksheets in excel. However, when I try to select multiple worksheets and then paste special only the first sheet gets the data.

I have also tried to paste without paste special only then the data is pasted in all the selected sheets.

I have created multiple sheets by using pivot option(pivot on a list of values and using pivot option - "Show report filter pages" I have achieved multiple worksheets with the sheet name required. But when all these worksheets are selected together and data as mentioned above is pasted it isn't pasted correctly or the data gets pasted on just one worksheet.

Is there a workaround this problem?